# Is $\frac{1}{z}e^{\ln(z)}$ defined for $ z = 0, z \in \mathbb{C} $

Tags: complex-analysis

$f(z) = \frac{1}{z}e^{\ln(z)}$ has a value of $1$ everywhere except perhaps at $z=0$. Ignoring $z=0$ it is holomorphic (being a constant real function).

Is it defined for $ z = 0, z \in \mathbb{C} $? Trying to take a limit and applying L’Hospital rule doesn’t help. You get the same expression as a quotient of derivatives of numerator and denominator. Is there another trick such as using squeeze theorem that could help?

Comment: What is $\ln(z)$?

Comment: $e^{ln(z)}=z$, so $f(z)=1$.  What to do about $z=0$ seems to be a matter of choice.

Comment: No it is not defined. That's a hole or removable singluarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, this function as you write it is not defined at $z=0$ because neither $1/z$ nor $\log(z)$ are defined for $z=0$. However, there exists a continuous (even holomorphic) continuation of the function to the whole of $\mathbb C$. Does that answer your question?

EDIT: Of course, we have $\lim_{z\to 0}\frac 1ze^{\log(z)} = 1$. No l'Hosppital needed, this is trivial. Look up the definition of limit.

Comment: Makes sense. Every $\Delta z$ yields 1 from this function, however small $|\Delta z|$ is. A follow up question: is it valid to use limit law of composite functions and write - in such a case - $\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{z}e^{\log(z)} = \frac{1}{\lim_{z \rightarrow 0}z} e^{\log(\lim_{z \rightarrow 0}z)}$ ? In other words, does the removable discontinuity hole cause problems when using composite rule of limits even though the function has analytical holomorphic continuation at the hole?

Comment: $\log(\lim_{z\to 0}z) = \log(0)$ does not exist. So no. You cannot write this.